# How to use inheritance in odoo to enhance form view?

Tags: odoo, openerp-7

In the Account and Finance module i want to add a new field but do not want to change the current form view and also I don't want to override it. I know to create a new class and declare _inherit attribute, declare new fields there, but i think it will override the original  form view.
I want both(original and inherited) form view to appear so that i can choose them based on my requirements. Is it possible?

(I desire to add discounts field in my inherited form view)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<openerp>
<data>
   <!-- 1st part of the sim_view start -->
   <record model="ir.ui.view" id="account.partner_view_buttons">
      <field name="name">partner.view.buttons</field>
      <field name="model">res.partner</field>
      <field name="inherit_id" ref="base.view_partner_form" />
      <field name="type">form</field>
      <field name="arch" type="xml">
         <xpath expr="//div[@name='buttons']" position="inside">
            <button type="action" class="oe_stat_button" id="invoice_button" icon="fa-pencil-square-o" name="464" attrs="{'invisible': [('customer', '=', False)]}" context="{'search_default_partner_id': active_id,'default_partner_id': active_id}">
            <div><strong><field name="total_invoiced" widget="monetary"/></strong><br/>Invoiced</div>
            </button>
        </xpath>
   </field>
```